# Why does a regular expression with a positive lookbehind in Visual Studio cause every second match to be substituted?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

Given the following regular expression containing a positive lookbehind (simplified from the one I'm actually trying to use):

```
(?<=\s|\n)(".*?")
```

and the following substitution expression:

```
_T($1)
```

Visual Studio 2013 will find every matching string but when replacing, will replace the string corresponding to the *subsequent* match, so will replace every second string.

Furthermore, `Replace All` does not work and says it cannot find any matching text (even though a `Find All` will find the relevant strings).

Is this a bug in Visual Studio or am I doing something wrong?

---

*Demo*:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. As an aside `(?<=\s|\n)` is exactly the same than `(?<=\s)`

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. I suspect it's a bug with handling the lookbehind, because replacing `(\s)(".*?")` with `$1_T($2)` replaces them all, as expected.

Comment: Ok, so, if I understand well it skips the first occurence of the line when you ask for a replacement. You have a very big mouse pointer *(please take it in a literal meaning)*

Comment: Couldn't fit more test cases in small window, but it skips every other one even in the same line (i.e., if that demo was on one line, it would still skip the 2nd and 4th).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Actually the `\n` does seem to be required in Visual Studio (even though the documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ae5bf541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, says otherwise!)

Comment: Thanks @Wiseguy.  A workaround is to use `([\s\n])(".*?")` for the regex and `$1_T($2)` for the substitution.

Comment: I've seen similar behavior. When using look-arounds in my RegEx expressions, Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and even 2015 may do weird stuff - replacing alternating instances instead of all. Replace All not doing anything, etc...

Comment: Just an update; the behavior in Visual Studio 2017 is the same. Use of look-ahead or look-behind structures in the regular expression cause the replacements to only occur on alternating instances, within the same file. Further, it never works on the first instance! So when one has run through a few dozen instances, replacing half of them, then repeats to get half the remaining, etc... until only one instance is left, the replacement fails. This is per-file, so if replacing in files, the first (or only) instance in each file is always skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** Visual Studio (VS) search/replace using VS Regexe's have to work with Visual Studio operations and what appears to be a valid regex will not work because of all the moving parts.

---

**Explanation** Because there are actually multiple things working against that lookbehind pattern *in visual studio*. Each of them is working in separately to achieve what you are seeing; but they are individual actions and not a cabal of one thought failure. Let me list them via 1/2/3:

---

**#1**:  When using any type of lookbehind/ahead in regular expression patterns, one must note that it **doesn't capture** what it specifies in the lookbehind. The capture happens on what comes after it. So your "Find Next" item doesn't capture the space or linefeed behind it. (It is what you want and this is logical) but see below how the space before it is not captured and each set is highlighted and how that interferes with the whole process.

[image: Individual matches using the lookbehind]

Stand alone this works and is what is intended, **as a search/highlight**, but then #2 comes into play.

---

**#2**: Visual Studio editor is not a true regex replace operation. Because it is doing a **two** step operation to do a replace; these steps are not integrated like a code regex replace. *Let that sink in.*

Step one is a find, step 2 is a replace. Replace all is multiple two step (Find/Replace) operations til end of file from current location.

On this single replace skip issue, on the first press, because `Replace Next` has to first find the next item, it doesn't replace it; *by design*  It *just* moves the highlight to the next "XXXXXX" string.

(Press 2) The user thinks Studio is going to replace what is highlighted, but that doesn't happen *in this case*, because the match pattern states that **the current match position** must have `\s|\n` within in it; curses, the lookbehind!

Because it doesn't have `\s|\n` of the lookbehind *in the current selection* it must move the text point which is the next location after the current highlight, and if found does a replace there.

[image]

To be clear, because the replace operation is sitting on a quote and not a `\s|\n` (**as directed by the pattern**), it *must* move the current pointer to the next `\s|\n` which it finds it and replaces the text. Note the two clicks in blue that happen to do the

---

**#3**: What is interesting is that if one doesn't do the match replacement, `$1`, but just some text, replace all works, uggg confusing.

[image]

Because the replace match `$1` is not viable in any individual search/replace step, the replace all the operation subsequently locks up.

---

**Summary**

What you want to do is logical, but because the regex replace with a lookbehind is jiggering with the editor pointer and the two step find/replace with regex operation, a conjunction of individual scenarios is causing the whole operation to fail.

One has to design a **visual studio** regex pattern to work with the #1/#2/#3 editor idiosyncrasies as pointed out above. **Keep in mind that VS regex is not true .NET regex parser...just a close one-off.**

Is it a bug? Maybe. But IMHO a fix would require a whole redesign of search/replace feature to be more *regex centric* than *plain text search centric* (with regex patterns) like it is now.